# MaxCharactersInDocument validation don't work

Tags: c#, validation, xmlreader

I try to validate maximum characters in xml document:

```
string xml = "<X><Y><Z></Z><Z></Z><Z></Z></Y></X>";

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                {
                    MaxCharactersInDocument = 10
                };

try
{
    using(var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        {
            using(var xr2 = XmlReader.Create(xr, settings))
            {
                while(xr2.Read()){} // MaxCharactersInDocument validation do not work
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The porpose is to validate external xml(received with XmlReader) for maximum charcters. Why MaxCharactersInDocument validation don't work for XmlReader created on another XmlReader? How can I do this validation differently?

Also, scheme validation works for second reader but max characters validation don't.

Comment: Why do you need two create statements?  You can add setting into first Create() method.

Comment: @jdweng, first reader is an external reader for some application. And the porpose is to validate external xml(received with XmlReader) for maximum charcters. Also, scheme validation works for second reader but max characters validation don't. Why?

Comment: It may be an encoding issue.  Adding to StringReader() parameter list an encoding method may solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at a [MSDN's working example for MaxCharactersInDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.maxcharactersindocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

The following will also work with your input:

```
        string markup = "<X><Y><Z></Z><Z></Z><Z></Z></Y></X>";

        //string markup = "<Root>Content</Root>";

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.MaxCharactersInDocument = 10;

    try
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(markup), settings);
        while (reader.Read()) { }
    }
    catch (XmlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Seems the `StringReader` object should be used as input in the `XmlReader.Create` method for it to work.

---

Output:

[image]